# lambda command to give an argument depending on what button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I have a function that searches a directory for `.json` files. I then have a button created for each `.json` file found (there is no set number of files). What I want to do if for a user to press the button which contains the file they want to use.

The code i have to try and achieve this is below:

```
    numLink = 0
    for i in list_of_json_files:
        basename = os.path.basename(str(i))
        filename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0].replace("_", " ")
        Button(loadCreate, text=filename.title(), command=lambda: open_use_existing_rink_book(numLink), pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=n, column=1, pady=5)
        n += 1
        numLink += 1
        print(numLink)
```

What I thought this would do is give each button a different number for the argument for the function `open_use_existing_rink_book()`, therefore allowing me to distinguish the button pressed. E.g. if there are 3 `.json` files (json1, json2, json3) if I click the button that has json2 as the text I want to know that that button has been pressed.

The only other way in which I can think of doing it is by passing the text of the button as the argument for `open_use_existing_rink_book()`, but I'm not sure how I would do this, maybe with a text variable?

Comment: Have you tried it without `lambda`? like this `command=open_use_existing_rink_book(numLink)`

Comment: @go2nirvana without `lambda` will lead to the problem of invoking function during the execution of intial code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ill just add an answer here, because its too long for the comments. Have you tried using the `enumerate()` function?

```
for index,i in enumerate(list_of_json_files):
    basename = os.path.basename(str(i))
    filename = os.path.splitext(basename)[0].replace("_", " ")
    Button(loadCreate, text=filename.title(), command=lambda i=index: open_use_existing_rink_book(i), pady=5, padx=5).grid(row=n, column=1, pady=5)
    n += 1
    print(index)
```

With this you can get rid of `numLink` as its the exact same thing. Also i dont know why your using `n` here as its undefined in the code you gave. Anyway keep in mind, you can replace `n` with `index` too.

The purpose of `enumerate()` is, it creates number for each item of the list, so you dont have to go on like a `while` loop. You can specify the starting number by `enumerate(lst,start=1)`, here it will start the count from one.

Hope this helped you out, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: That's worked thank you @Cool Cloud. Sorry I missed off the n = 3, but i will use the index now. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. The way you are doing it it will always pass the final value of `numLink`. You have to change your `lambda` to the below for it to work.

```
lambda nl=numLink: open_use_existing_rink_book(nl)
```

The reason why is simple. In your version you are just passing a reference of `numLink` to your function so, all calls will be to whatever numLink's ultimate value is. In the version I showed you the current value of `numLink` is being stored in `nl` and that value is being passed to your function.

Comment: Oops, we do have the same answer, kindof ;)

Comment: Thank you @Michael Guidry!!

Comment: I didn't realize that you can only accept 1 answer, even if both were correct. I accepted Cool Could's first, so thought it was only decorous for me to accept his